# Batch Script to merge tab fles in a directory

Tags: mapinfo, ogr2ogr, merge, tab, bash

Very similar to this question [Merging multiple .tab files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/merging-multiple-tab-files) can someone please help me with a batch script for this?

Based on the answer in the above I have

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.tab;
do 
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.tab i  -f “MapInfo File” -nln merge 
done
```

but when I run it it fails with

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `i' with the following drivers.
```

and then lists the drivers

Comment: I recommend some bash scripting tutorial like https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial. I see some dollar signs in the examples.

Comment: +1 `ogr2ogr -update -append merge.tab $i  -f “MapInfo File” -nln merge`

Comment: Thanks @dmci.  That worked.  There was an issue with the first " in "MapInfo File" but changed to `ogr2ogr -update -append merge.tab $i -f "MapInfo File" -nln merge` and all seems good :)

Comment: Copy-paste can indeed make such trouble. What looks like " may actually be “ which is another character and command fails. The minus sign - is another beast. Writing the command from keyboard usually helps.

Comment: @dmci, sounds like your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, and based on the above comments, this should work:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.tab $i -f “MapInfo File” -nln merge
```