# Batch JSON to Features script needed

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, geojson, pyscripter

I have a folder on my local drive with 1,500+ JSON files (lines) that I need converted to shapefiles. I've tried creating a batch model in Python and ModelBuilder without success.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 and PyScripter.

Via KHibma: (this is not yet working for me, maybe someone can chime in)

```
import arcpy
import os

dirOfJSON = 'c:/temp/jsons'
outputDIrectory = 'c:/temp/jsonSHPs'

arcpy.env.workspace = dirOfJSON

for f in arcpy.ListFiles('.json'):
    j = os.path.join(dirOfJSON, f)
    outputShp = os.path.join(outputDIrectory, os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".shp")
    print("Processing : {}".format(outputShp))
    arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(j, outputShp)
```

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: Rather similar question today http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216281/bash-script-to-merge-tab-fles-in-a-directory. Same approach will work, not much to do with GIS really.

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 and Pyscripter.

Comment: Does `JSONToFeatures` work on a single JSON file of yours?  What happens when you run that code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl, make sure to update the directories.

```
import arcpy
import os

dirOfJSON = 'c:/temp/jsons'
outputDIrectory = 'c:/temp/jsonSHPs'

arcpy.env.workspace = dirOfJSON

for f in arcpy.ListFiles('.json'):
    j = os.path.join(dirOfJSON, f)
    outputShp = os.path.join(outputDIrectory, os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".shp")
    print("Processing : {}".format(outputShp))
    arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(j, outputShp)
```

Comment: This does not seem to give me any response when run through PyScripter or Python module in ArcMap. I did also update the directories on the script.